# Oauth issue with LinkedIn API from Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, linkedin

I have a requirement to get profile data from Linkedin into Salesforce.

```
public class linkedinauth {
    public String x{get;set;}
    public static final string REDIRECT_URL='https://test.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/*****000000Ua7EAE/LinkedIn';
    public static final string LINKEDIN_API_KEY='******ahx9s8jg';
    public static final string OAUTH_CODE_END_POINT_URL='https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code';
    public static final string SCOPE='r_basicprofile';
    public static final string STATE='75etfdcdgsdvvsdgd'; 

   public PageReference connect(){
     x=OAUTH_CODE_END_POINT_URL+'&client_id='+LINKEDIN_API_KEY+'&scope='+SCOPE+'&state='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(STATE,'UTF-8')+'&redirect_uri='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(REDIRECT_URL,'UTF-8');
     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(x);
     return pageRef; 
   }
}
```

However, I get this error message:

> We can't log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
>   No_Oauth_State: State was not valid

Step1: Asking for LinkedIn:

[image: Login]

Step2: Once I login I am getting this bellow error:

[image: Error]

Comment: This seems more of a stackoverflow question. Not very related to Salesforce.

Comment: @LanceShi: I am retrieving the data from Salesforce only.

Comment: No. You are retrieving data into Salesforce. And the process isn't very different whether it is in a Visualforce page or a plain html page

Comment: IMO, save yourself some trouble and just pay them for the use of their App on the App Exchange. But, it's your development time if you want to reinvent the wheel and spend your API calls.

Comment: @crmprogdev: Just updated my description with some progress. the reason behind the customization is to store the data inside salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works just fine for me.

Unfortunately we do not have enough information to tell you where your code is wrong so I would suggest you check your code to ensure the proper value of state. You can use the below for a guide as it works properly and has been testes as a MVR

**CLASS**

```
public with sharing class oAuth_Controller{


public string theCode {get;set;}
public string theTokenResponse {get;set;}

        /*******************************************
        *
        *   Get Authorization Code
        *
        *******************************************/

        public pagereference auth_Step_1(){

            String auth_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization';
            String params =  
                                '?response_type=code' +
                                '&client_id=XXXXX' +
                                '&redirect_uri=https://ap1.salesforce.com/apex/testOAuth' + 
    //                            '&prompt=consent' + 
                                '&scope=' + encodingUtil.URLEncode('r_basicprofile r_emailaddress w_share','UTF-8') +
                                '&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424';
                pageReference pr = New PageReference(auth_url + params);            
                return pr;
        }

        /*******************************************
        *
        *   Get Access Token
        *
        *******************************************/


        public pagereference auth_Step_2(){

            if(apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('state') != 'DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424')
                return null;

            theCode = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            Http http = new Http();

            String auth_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken';
            String params =  
                                '?code=' + apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') +
                                '&grant_type=authorization_code' + 
                                '&client_id=XXXXX' +
                                '&client_secret=XXXXXX' + 
                                '&redirect_uri=https://ap1.salesforce.com/apex/testOAuth';

            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setEndpoint(auth_url + params);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            req.setHeader('Content-Length',string.valueOf(req.getBody().length()));

            HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);


            theTokenResponse = resp.getBody();

            return null;

        }


    }
```

**Test VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="oAuth_Controller" action="{!auth_step_2}">

<apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!auth_Step_1}" value="Start" reRender="results"/>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputPanel id="results">

{!theTokenResponse}

</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: That was perfect solution, Thank you so much. I will take it from here. I will keep you updated if anything comes up. Thanks:)